# Why can an Apex Rest service not be annodated as @ReadOnly?

Tags: apex, rest-service

In apex you can create your own REST services quite simply:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/DUMMY/v1/*')
global class REST_Service {
@HttpGet
    global static string getDummytMessage(){
        return 'DUMMY DATA';
    }
}
```

Salesforce does not allow such a class to be annotated as `@ReadOnly`, I would like to **understand** and know why this is the case.

**update**: potentially there is no technical reason and its just not there out of a project management perspective. I've created [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kourAAA) to put it on the radar.

Comment: It looks like Salesforce implemented support for the `@ReadOnly` annotation in Summer '20 (API Version 49). Nice!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thats a good question, and a reasonable one given that it is [supported for Web Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm) defined via Apex. As to the reason for this, given both contexts are functionally the same from our perspective as developers. I am at a loss as to provide a reasonable hypothesis outside of knowning the code base of the platform.

I would suggest raising an IdeaExchange for it (had a quick check and could not see one) and perhaps raising a support case to enquiry as to if this is at all on the immediate radar to release this support.

Comment: Had not thought of posting it as an idea, have done so now. If no one offers a different perspective I'll accept your answer as such.

Comment: Did you raise an idea, I'd be happy to vote it up for you, if so? :)

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with it too. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kourAAA

Comment: Just upvoted and commented for ya! :)